# How to send an email with laravel?

Tags: laravel

I amtrying to send an email in a Laravel project, and it works in Localhost, but I have a lot of problems in a web server.
This is what appears now:
[image]

What does it means?

This is the ENV:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=ltomicb@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=merluzadepincho@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Merluza de Pincho"
```

Controller:

```
    public function mail(request $request){
    Mail::to('ltomicb@gmail.com')->send(new mdpMail($request));
    Session::flash('mensaje_enviado','Mensaje enviado correctamente.');
    return redirect('/contacto');
}
```

I have tried with mailgun but it was impossible to use it in a web server too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enable your 2 step verification from gmail account.

https://myaccount.google.com/security

then use the generated key from there to your ENV_PASSWORD instead your real password.

Comment: Ok, now I have another problem. I have just upload it in the post

Comment: Well at least you got another error, this is another issue now. Do another post

Comment: Ok, i'll do it now

Comment: Well, I have to wait 90 minutes to do it :(